# System.ArgumentException: 'PKCS8 data must be contained within '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----' and '-----END PRIVATE KEY-----'

Tags: c#, json, firebase-realtime-database

I make a project on datacloud using c# but when I run it I get an error.
here my code:

```
public FirebaseCloudMessageHandler(string keydata)
{
    FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions()
    {
        Credential = GoogleCredential.FromJson(keydata)
    });
}
public async Task<Result> SendNotifyToADeviceAsync(string registrationToken, Message message)
{
    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(message.Payload);
    var fireBaseMessage = new FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.Message()
    {
        Data = data,
        Token = registrationToken
    };
    string response = await FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendAsync(fireBaseMessage);
    if (response == null)
    {
        var failText = new List<string>();
        failText.Add(registrationToken);
        return Result.Error(failText.ToString());
    }
    return Result.Successfully;
}
```

and

```
public static class DummyData
{
    public static string JsonKeyString =
    "my convert: json - string";
}
```

main:

```
var token = "my-token";
var handler = new FirebaseCloudMessageHandler(DummyData.JsonKeyString);
var result = await handler.SendNotifyToADeviceAsync(token, new Message
{
    Title = "Test title",
    Context = "Test message"
});

Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result));
```

here my private_key after converted:

```
\"private_key\":\"-----BEGINPRIVATEKEY-----\\n+key+\\n-----ENDPRIVATEKEY-----\\n\";
```

please someone help me with this

Comment: Are you passing `"-----BEGINPRIVATEKEY-----\\n+key+\\n-----ENDPRIVATEKEY-----\\n"`  to the constructor, or the string `"\"private_key\":\"-----BEGINPRIVATEKEY-----\\n+key+\\n-----ENDPRIVATEKEY-----\\n\""`? In the last case, you might need to replace `GoogleCredential.FromJson(keydata)` by something like `GoogleCredential.FromJson(keydata).private_key`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The cause is that the code used in the library is environment specific, and will work differently depending on the machine running the code. For me, it was a Linux server.

The fix is to remove all the line break characters in the private key:

```
\"private_key\":\"-----BEGINPRIVATEKEY-----+key+-----ENDPRIVATEKEY-----";
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, After spending a few hours I found that during the deserialization of the JSON somehow .net changes the private key value

From

> -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----

To

> -----BEGINPRIVATEKEY-----

Refactoring the value solved the issue
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I removed the "\n" from the private key and everything worked. When you paste the private key in notepad++ it looks likes [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZP2f.png)

You see how the "\n" is in blue.

Answer (score -1):

Eye: should do several changes on the \n

```
\"private_key\": \"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- \\n MIIEvgIBADANBgkqIBAQDAEfBdvAmxdTBJ \\n E6YSEe831QJHwL3l/lH79HT2 \\n -----END PRIVATE KEY-----\\n\"
```